# Add a new column to dataframe and add unique values to each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns: id_code & diagnosis

I have a folder with images with filename same as id_code. I want to add a new columns to the dataframe: Image, height and width

I have the following code:

```
for idx, row in df_train.iterrows():
    img = Image.open('train_images/{}.png'.format(row['id_code']))
    height, width = img.size
    row['image'] = img
    row['height'] = height
    row['width'] = width
```

I tried using `df_train.iloc[idx]['image'] = img` instead of `row['image'] = img` and so on for the rest of the lines of code but that would give me an error.

But this code updates the row but doesn't update the dataframe itself.

Comment: What is the class `Image`? What module does it come from?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I'm using Image from the PIL library

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Thanks for pointing the indentation; I just copied from my workspace and somehow it did not adapt the spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should assign it cell by cell

```
l=[]
for idx, row in df_train.iterrows():
    img = Image.open('train_images/{}.png'.format(row['id_code']))
    l.append(img)
    height, width = img.size
    df.loc[idx,'height'] = height
    df.loc[idx,'width'] = width

df['img']=l
```

Comment: I tried this as well I get the following error: 
`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'PngImageFile'` at the code line `df.loc[idx, 'image'] = img`

Comment: @AdarshRavi For the line img, what kind of structure  is that ?

Comment: It's a PNG image; Initially I tried doing df['image'] = img it would just reassign the entire image column with the last image in the iteration.

Comment: Sounds to me like the `image` columns has its dtype set as `int`. We need to see more of your code. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish there's not much code before the lines I have posted except for a read_csv which creates the df_train dataframe